# AR Quiver Arrows for Gentle Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, homological-algebra

I've been working on calculating the Auslander-Reiten quiver for a particular quiver, guided by the framework set out in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05802. Identifying the string modules was straightforward, yet I'm struggling with pinpointing the arrows accurately within the AR quiver.

I'm aware of how the complete AR quiver should appear, and I'm using this example to better understand the method for gentle algebras. However, the arrows are proving to be a bit elusive in my computations.

I would be very grateful for any insights or explanations that could help clarify the correct approach to determine these arrows. This puzzle has kept me occupied for several days, and I'm keen to solve it with your expertise.

I am looking forward to your thoughts, and many thanks in advance!

Here is the link to the picture:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yylvj.jpg

Comment: Thank you, I have replaced the picture. I already know about the knitting method. However, I would like to use this new method for gentle algebras.